# Send Value To Textboxes in another opened form?

Tags: c#, winforms

I Have `Winform` Application
Have 2 Forms 1's Name `Tree` 2'nd Name `AddRegion` Which Have 3 Controls Public Modifiers 
i am sending Values From Tree To AddRegion Controls it work correctly but open new AddRegion 
how i can Send Values in opened Form

```
//  this is button cick in Tree 
Definitions.AddRegion addreg = new Definitions.AddRegion();
addreg .txt_accno.Text  ="1";
addreg .txt_acconame.Text  = "2";
addreg.lbl_ParentID.Text ="3";
addreg.ShowInTaskbar = false;
//  addreg.Show(this);
this.Hide();
```

Comment: Get data in "AddRegion" by using some events, or using Button and Click event

Comment: You can send a reference to form1 one in the constructor of form2 and make the controls you want to update public.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this method,

```
for (int i = 0; i < Application.OpenForms.Count; i++)
{
    if (Application.OpenForms[i].Name == "YourFormName")
    {
        YourForm form = (YourForm)Application.OpenForms[i];
        ///Assign the value here
        ///form.txt_accno.Text = "1"; //etc.
    }
}
```

**EDITE:**

Even you can use LINQ to find open form.

```
var forms =  (from Form form in Application.OpenForms
                            where form.Name == "Form2"
                            select form)
```

How about this

```
YourForm form = (YourForm)Application.OpenForms["formName"];
```

Comment: this is not bad and get my goal but  i use this Tree ( search ) in more than 31 Form :S

Comment: You can use LINQ to find open form. I have updated my answer please take a look.

Comment: Thanks for your effort i wanna easier way i will mark as answer already worked !

Answer (score -1):

keep the Definitions.AddRegion form in a variable outside of methode.

So it will be global, and accessible, like:

```
Definitions.AddRegion addreg = new Definitions.AddRegion();

void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
    addreg .txt_accno.Text  ="1";
    addreg .txt_acconame.Text  = "2";
    addreg.lbl_ParentID.Text ="3";
    addreg.ShowInTaskbar = false;
    this.Hide();
}
```

Comment: Same ! open new instance